# Three.js + OrbitControls - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am writing a class for rotating cube, but every time i rotate it or zoom, i get an error "Cannot read property 'render' of undefined". What am i doing wrong? I guess something is wrong with the scopes. Here is my class:

```
myclass = function() {
    this.camera = null;
    this.scene = null;
    this.renderer = null;
    this.product = null;

    this.init = function (container) {
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = createCamera();
        this.product = createProduct();
        this.scene.add(this.product);
        this.createRenderer();
        this.setControls();
        container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        this.animate();

    };

    function createCamera() {
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(20, 300 / 400, 1, 10000);
        camera.position.z = 1800;
        return camera;
    }

    function createProduct() {
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 200, 200);
        var materials = ...;

    var product = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    return product;
    }
    this.createRenderer = function () {
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
    this.renderer.setSize(this.sceneWidth, this.sceneHeight);
     };

    this.setControls = function () {
    this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
    this.controls.addEventListener('change', this.render);
    };

    this.animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));
        this.render();
    };

    this.render = function () {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };
 };
```

Tnanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a scoping problem in the callback specified here:

```
this.controls.addEventListener( 'change', this.render );
```

In your class, add

```
var scope = this;
```

Then rewrite your `render()` method like so:

```
this.render = function () {

    scope.renderer.render( scope.scene, scope.camera );

};
```

Also, the point of adding the event listener is to remove the animation loop.

So..., remove it, and only render when the mouse causes the camera to move.

You will also have to call `render()` once initially, and after models load.

three.js r.69

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind method as follows it will hold the scope for the render method

```
this.controls.addEventListener( 'change', this.render.bind(this) );
```